# Bootstrap 4 Transparent navigation bar

Tags: navbar

please am working on a transparent navbar and its background color changing on scroll. And is working perfectly fine.

But i need help in its navbar-link color changing also.Have not been able to do this.Have tried but all my effort in making the nav-link color change with the background color on scroll are not working.
Below the image of my codes...

[image]

[image]
Solution please would so much appreciate.

Comment: You need to provide code for the problem that you have.

Comment: Post a minimal working example of your problem, and I can have a look. CodePen  (or similar) or directly in the post, is fine. Cheers

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. This makes it difficult for us to test your code locally.